# How to center orphans in a Flutter Wrap layout that adds space between in other lines?

Tags: flutter

I want to wrap widgets in a layout such that it applies `spaceBetween` if multiple widgets fit on the main axis, but *center* any orphan widgets.

E.g.:

If there is sufficient space, the layout is like `alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween`:

```
|A--BB--CCCC|
```

But if the space is constrained it should wrap the orphaned widget to the center of the next line (instead of the start of the line) like `alignment: WrapAlignment.center` would:

```
|A-----BB|
|--CCCC--|
```

And if there is even less room, all widgets wrap as orphans:

```
|-A--|
|-BB-|
|CCCC|
```

How can I achieve this, given that all widgets would impose their preferred size (like text widgets of an unpredictable width)?